# Python "Requests" install issue - HTTPBasicAuth

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm on a mac and have tried the following:

`easy_install requests`

and

`pip install requests`

When I try `import requests` command in REPL python I get the following error

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "requests.py", line 4, in <module>
    from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
ImportError: No module named auth
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You have a local module named `requests.py` in your current directory. Rename that file, it is masking the installed library.

What is happening in your traceback:

1. Python tries to find `requests` and the first item on the `sys.path` search path is a file named `requests.py`, it fits the requirements.
2. The file contains the line `from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth`, Python tries to import that.
3. Python already has a module `requests` imported (from step 1), but since it is a plain module and not a package, an `ImportError` is thrown.